# NSLayoutConstraint outlets are allways nil while other outlets aren't

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm instantiating a shop via a xib:

```
let cShop = UINib(nibName: "connectedShop", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! connectedShop
```

This shop has assigned this custom class:

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit
class connectedShop : UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewLeft: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerViewRight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var banerDiscount: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerImageShop: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bannerButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func bannerButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
}
```

And from the code I'm calling this shop like this:

```
let cShop = UINib(nibName: "connectedShop", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! connectedShop


cShop.bannerTitle.text = "shopTitle"  //work


shopContainer.addSubview(cShop)

cShop.bannerViewLeft.constant = 0  //make my app crash
cShop.bannerViewRight.constant = 0 // "
cShop.bannerViewTop.constant = 0  //  "
```

When I set the `bannerTitle.text` property my app continues and debugging I see this outlet is initialized, but the constraints aren't and when the compiler are in the line that assign a constant, it always throw the same error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

debugging I've seen there is one outlet that is initialized:

[image]

Does anybody know why this can be happening?

These are my conections:

[image]

Comment: Could you show please how you have connected them in Interface Builder?

Comment: Edited to add a picture of my connections

Comment: Can you call `print(cShop.bannerTitle.text)` ? Setting the value will not cause a crash if the receiver is nil, that's why it doesn't crash on this line, but the `bannerTitle` may be also nil.

Comment: I checked and it's not nil. Also, there is an outlet that is not nil, only one, bannerViewHight, the first one of the custom class. How this can be? I don't understand...

Comment: Could you select your connectedShop in Intreface Builder and then the Connections Inspector on the right? You will be able to see all of the outlets connected.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve it thanks to @fiks answer. It was more simple that I was expecting. Some outlets weren't correct. I managed to saw it thanks to the connections inspector

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue.
Change your constraint outlets to strong.

Comment: This solves my problem, however I didn't understand why it has worked. Can you explain its reason? @SergioM

Comment: @YusufKamilAK sure. Since the reference is weak the ref to the constraint will be dropped at some point in the life cycle.

Comment: @SergioM This doesn't really explain where the problem is.

Comment: Sure, so in my case the view was a cell. An when the cell was re used the constraints where deallocated since the refs are weak.

Answer (score 24):

How to make constraint outlets Strong:
Just remove weak from declaration.

```
@IBOutlet weak var bannerViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

to

```
@IBOutlet var bannerViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Do it for all and thats it.